# deployment angular +2 apache

Tags: angular, apache, deployment, build

I'm, trying to deploy my Angular project, but I keep getting:

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1A0R.png)

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong at this point, I can see my browser is well aware of the existence of my files, but I can't whatever reason load them.

I've tried running

```
ng build --prod
ng build --prod base-href path --prod
ng build --prod base-href path
```

Am I missing anything totally obvious?

Comment: this type of errors generally are because your server try to get the bundles files (the .js) and call in an error page (not return the .js else an html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,  so it is not necessary a angular problem, but more of a apache problem I need to fix?

Comment: if you has no error when you build, I'm almost secure that the problem is in apache server, sorry, I don't know about apache server

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a rewrite rule in your apache configuration, so it returns index.html allways.

Please see : https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Edit : also see : https://gist.github.com/rambabusaravanan/578df6d2486a32c3e7dc50a4201adca4

```
# To host on root path just use  "<Location />" for http://mydomainname.in
# To host on non-root path use "<Location /myreactapp>" for http://mydomainname.in/mypath
# If non-root path, don't forgot to add "homepage": "/myreactapp" in your app's package.json
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomainname.in
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Location /myreactapp >
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule . /myreactapp/index.html [L]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work... I still get the errors.